# call to undefined function msg()

Tags: php

i m getting an error in the php code..
Fatal error: Call to undefined function msg()
but the function is already defined in the code here
whenever i click on a login button this login script runs

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("elunika", $con);
$a = $_POST['em'];
$b = $_POST['pwd'];
$c = $_POST['log'];
$b = md5($b);

if (isset($c)) {
    $q = mysql_query("select * from registeration where email='$a' and password='$b'");
    $r = mysql_num_rows($q);
    if ($r) {
        $_SESSION["Authenticated"] = 1;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $a;
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION["Authenticated"] = 0;
    }

    if ($_SESSION["Authenticated"] === 0) {
        die(msg(0, "Incorrect Information"));
    }
    else {
        session_write_close();
        echo msg(1, "profile.php");
    }

    function msg($status, $txt)
    {
        return '{"status":' . $status . ',"txt":"' . $txt . '"}';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you ever considered to indent your code properly? Additionally, please do NOT USE STRING FUNCTIONS TO GENERATE JSON. Use `return json_encode(['status' => $status, 'txt' => $txt]);` instead! Using unsalted md5 hashes is also bad. And the mysql_* functions are deprecated in favour of mysqli/PDO. Your code is full of SQL injection holes by the way.

Comment: PHP hasn't reached the `function msg(...)` bit by the time you actually TRY calling msg(), so yes... it's undefined at the time you try calling it. move the function definition to the top of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only unscoped functions are defined at compile-time (prior to execution). Your msg function however is just going to be defined if the if branch (the `if (isset(…))` on line 9) is entered; so it's only going to be defined at the moment where the executor reaches it.

But in your code `msg()` is already called before the function declaration was encountered at run-time. Moving the function declaration up (= before the `msg()` call) should help:

```
function msg ($status, $txt) {
    return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
}

if($_SESSION["Authenticated"] === 0) {
    die(msg(0,"Incorrect Information"));
} else {
    session_write_close();
    echo msg(1,"profile.php");
}
```